# A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an application in flutter/dart and
I'm trying to check if the returned route information is empty before proceeding with the rest of the route building, I'm doing that inside the "factory", and if isEmpty I'm returning **null** however, I'm getting the following error
**"A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the constructor 'Directions.fromMap' because it has a return type of 'Directions'"**
Thanks for your support

```
class Directions{
  final LatLngBounds bounds; 
  final List<PointLatLng> plylinePoints;
  final String totalDistance;
  final String totalDuration;

  const Directions ({
    required this.bounds, required this.plylinePoints,
    required this.totalDistance, required this.totalDuration
  });

  factory Directions.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
        if ((map['routes'] as List).isEmpty) return null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `factory` constructor in **Dart** only allow you to return an *instance* of the *class* or of a *subclass*. You can't return `null` from it.

What you could do instead is to use a `static Directions? fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)` **function**.

That way you would be able to *return* either a `Direction` or `null`

Answer (score 0):

```
static Directions? from Map(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    // Check if the route is not available
    if ((map['routes'] as List).isEmpty) {
      return null;
    }
```

It may help you. Now you can return `null`.